# How to fit a parallelogram to XY Data

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I want to fit (the best/closest possible) parallelogram to a set of XY data points and obtain the co-ordinates of the vertices.

1. The X and Y data are two independent sinusoidal type of waves, which on plotting against each other give a parallelogram-like Lissajous figure. Example data can be found in this link -- [Example Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38176701/sample_data.csv)
2. The parallelogram (almost) always has the 4 vertices in four different quadrants.

At the moment I am manually fitting a parallelogram to extract the co-ordinates. I have 60 such data sets. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. (I am new to Mathematica).

EDIT: The result of

```
BoundingRegion[myData, "MinOrientedRectangle"]
```

in yellow in the linked image is not what I am trying to obtain in this case. The red lines in the image is what I am trying to achieve, and then extract the cyan coloured co-ordinates.

[image]

Comment: `BoundingRegion[pts, "MinOrientedRectangle"]` could be a useful starting point.

Comment: @jackryan - your image didn't come through, it seems like an empty jpeg

Comment: @JasonB Apologies; I just added a link to the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, the way we want to solve that is easy. We'll look at the distance to the center. This gives us a data function we can fit with a trigonometric function.

So lets start:

```
lData=Sqrt[Plus@@(#^2)]&/@data; (*compute distance data*)
maxAmplitude=Max[lData]; (*find maximum*)
lpData=Table[{i/Length[lData]*10Pi,lData[[i]]/maxAmplitude*2},{i,1,Length[lData]}]; (*rescale data to [0,10Pi] and [0,2]*)

fit=NonlinearModelFit[lpData,Cos[a*x+b]+1,{a,b},x]; (*fit with a simple cosine function*)

Show[ListPlot[lpData,PlotStyle->Black],Plot[fit["BestFit"],{x,0,10Pi},PlotStyle->Red],Graphics[{Blue,PointSize[Large],Point[{#,2}]&/@Table[(-b+2Pi*i)/a/.fit["BestFitParameters"],{i,1,5}]}]] (*display result*)
```

> [image]

The next task is pretty starightforward. We search for the Max,Min-Points. We know that:

$$x_{max}=\frac{-b+2\pi\cdot n}{a}$$
$$x_{min}=\frac{-b+2\pi\cdot n+\pi}{a}$$

With $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So we can use that to rescale to our data-range. We'll get multiple points so we take the average from them:

```
mulCornerData=data[[Round[Length[data]*(Table[(-b+Pi*i)/a/.fit["BestFitParameters"],{i,1,10}]/(10Pi))]]];
cornerData={Mean[mulCornerData[[#]]&/@{1,5,9}],Mean[mulCornerData[[#]]&/@{2,6,10}],Mean[mulCornerData[[#]]&/@{3,7}],Mean[mulCornerData[[#]]&/@{4,8}]};
Show[ListPlot[data,PlotStyle->Black],ListLinePlot[cornerData[[Mod[#,4]+1]]&/@Range[0,4],PlotStyle->Red]]
```

> [image]

Comment: You made it so simple; Very big thanks! Is there way to add a constraint to strictly get all co-ordinates in different quadrants?

Answer (score 7):

There is already an answer, but I think with less assumptions we can create a better fit.

After loading the data I transformed them in polar coordinates (angle, radius) and chopped off the first pair.

```
dataTransf = {ArcTan[First@#, Last@#], Norm[#]} & /@ data[[2 ;;]];
```

In polar coordinates you can represent a line with the $Csc(\phi-\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle of the line.
With this knowledge we build a function of 5 (as there are some data points prior to the first peak).
We got 2 pair of lines, were each has the same angle, but different signum.

```
fitfunc = Piecewise[{
{-c2 Csc[ϕ - ϕ2], ϕ < a - π},
{c1 Csc[ϕ - ϕ1], a - π <= ϕ <= -π + b},
{c2 Csc[ϕ - ϕ2], -π + b < ϕ < a},
{-c1 Csc[ϕ - ϕ1], a <= ϕ <= b},
{-c2 Csc[ϕ - ϕ2], a < ϕ < π + a}}]
```

To become an rectangle the lines have to be continuous. So we use continuity conditions at a and b:

```
-c2 Csc[a - ϕ2] == c1 Csc[a - ϕ1]
c1 Csc[b - ϕ1] == c2 Csc[b - ϕ2]
```

And solve those for a and b to get:
**Edit:** Of coure Mathematica can do this

```
Solve[-c2 Csc[a - ϕ2] == c1 Csc[a - ϕ1], a]
Solve[c1 Csc[b - ϕ1] == c2 Csc[b - ϕ2], b]
```

You get 4 possible solutions each and I have to admitt: I dont know why but it works fine with the 2nd solution for a and the 3rd for b.

```
{a -> ArcCos[-((c2 Cos[ϕ1] + c1 Cos[ϕ2])/Sqrt[
c2^2 Cos[ϕ1]^2 + 2 c1 c2 Cos[ϕ1] Cos[ϕ2] + 
 c1^2 Cos[ϕ2]^2 + c2^2 Sin[ϕ1]^2 + 
 2 c1 c2 Sin[ϕ1] Sin[ϕ2] + c1^2 Sin[ϕ2]^2])],
b->ArcCos[(c2 Cos[ϕ1] - c1 Cos[ϕ2])/Sqrt[
c2^2 Cos[ϕ1]^2 - 2 c1 c2 Cos[ϕ1] Cos[ϕ2] + 
c1^2 Cos[ϕ2]^2 + c2^2 Sin[ϕ1]^2 - 
2 c1 c2 Sin[ϕ1] Sin[ϕ2] + c1^2 Sin[ϕ2]^2]]}
```

By replacing those in the equation we reduce it to 4 parameters 
    $\phi 1$, $\phi 2$, $c1$, $c2$.
Now after all the prework we can actually fit.

```
fitmod = NonlinearModelFit[dataTransf, 
fitfunc, {{ϕ1, -1}, ϕ2, c1, {c2, 100}}, ϕ];
```

Here we have to take care of the intial values. (-1 for \ϕ1 and 100 for c2 do the job.)

Now we plot it nicely

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-3600, 3600}, {-800, 800}}],
PolarPlot[fitmod[ϕ], {ϕ, -π, π}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0, 1, 1]]], 
ImageSize -> Large]

Show[ListPlot[dataTransf, PlotRange -> {-1000, 3600}], 
Plot[fitmod[ϕ], {ϕ, -π, π}, 
PlotRange -> {-1000, 3300}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[0.0, 1, 1]]], 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

and get:

[image: DataFit]

[image]

**Edit2:**

```
fitmod["BestFitParameters"]
```

gives the parameters. 
The parameter $a,b,a+\pi,b+\pi$ describe the angles of the vertices and evaluating `fitfunc` there gives the radius. Then we can use:

$$x=r \sin(\phi)$$
$$y=r\cos(\phi)$$

If there are still any questions concerning the math or the code let me know.

Comment: pretty cool. Well done.

Comment: @meneken17 Very elegant approach (took 3-4 hour to understand the maths). \[Phi]1 = 0 worked on Mathematica v11.
1. Could you please put the code for solution to a and b. 2. Also, how can I extract the co-ordinates of the four vertices? Thank you.